# Use data.table to select non-unique rows

Tags: r, unique, data.table, subset

I have a large table consisting of several genes (newID) with associated values. Some genes (newID) are unique, some have several instances (appear in multiple rows). How to exclude from the table those with only one occurrence (row)? IN the example below, only the last row would be removed as it is unique.

```
head(exons.s, 10)
                       Row.names exonID    pvalue log2fold.5_t.GFP_t.              newID
1  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E001   E001 0.3597070         0.029731989 ENSMUSG00000000001
2  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E002   E002 0.6515167         0.028984837 ENSMUSG00000000001
3  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E003   E003 0.8957798         0.009665072 ENSMUSG00000000001
4  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E004   E004 0.5308266        -0.059273822 ENSMUSG00000000001
5  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E005   E005 0.4507640        -0.061276835 ENSMUSG00000000001
6  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E006   E006 0.5147357        -0.068357886 ENSMUSG00000000001
7  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E007   E007 0.5190718        -0.063959853 ENSMUSG00000000001
8  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E008   E008 0.8999434         0.032186993 ENSMUSG00000000001
9  ENSMUSG00000000001_Gnai3:E009   E009 0.5039369         0.133313175 ENSMUSG00000000001
10  ENSMUSG00000000003_Pbsn:E001   E001        NA                  NA ENSMUSG00000000003
> dim(exons.s)
[1] 234385      5
```

With plyr I would go about it like this:

```
## remove single exon genes:
multEx <- function(df){
   if (nrow(df) > 1){return(df)}
}

genes.mult.ex <- ddply(exons.s , .(newID), multEx, .parallel=TRUE)
```

But this is very slow. I thought this would be easy with data.table but I can't figure it out:

```
exons.s <- data.table(exons.s, key="newID")
x.dt.out <- exons.s[, lapply(.SD, multEx), by=newID]
```

I am new to data.table so any pointers in the right direction would be welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a column giving the number of rows in each group, then subset:

```
exons.s[,n:=.N,by=newID]
exons.s[n>1]
```

Comment: alternatively, if you do not want to assign a new column:   `exons.s[,c(.SD,n=.N),by=newID][n>1]`

Comment: as far as syntax simplicity goes, I think this is the most natural version: `exons.s[, .SD[.N>1], by=newID]`

Answer (score 2):

There is a simpler and more effiecent way of doing this using the duplicated() function instead of counting the group sizes.

First we need to generate a test dastaset:

```
# Generate test datasets
smallNumberSampled <- 1e3
largeNumberSampled <- 1e6

smallDataset <- data.table(id=paste('id', 1:smallNumberSampled, sep='_'), value1=sample(x = 1:26, size = smallNumberSampled, replace = T), value2=letters[sample(x = 1:26, size = smallNumberSampled, replace = T)])
largeDataset <- data.table(id=paste('id', 1:largeNumberSampled, sep='_'), value1=sample(x = 1:26, size = largeNumberSampled, replace = T), value2=letters[sample(x = 1:26, size = largeNumberSampled, replace = T)])

# add 2 % duplicated rows:
smallDataset <- rbind(smallDataset, smallDataset[sample(x = 1:nrow(smallDataset), size = nrow(smallDataset)* 0.02)])
largeDataset <- rbind(largeDataset, largeDataset[sample(x = 1:nrow(largeDataset), size = nrow(largeDataset)* 0.02)])
```

Then we implement the three solutions as functions:

```
# Original suggestion
getDuplicatedRows_Count <- function(dt, columnName) {
    dt[,n:=.N,by=columnName]
    return( dt[n>1] )
}

# Duplicated using subsetting
getDuplicatedRows_duplicated_subset <- function(dt, columnName) {
    # .. means "look up one level"
    return( dt[which( duplicated(dt[, ..columnName]) | duplicated(dt[, ..columnName], fromLast = T)  ),] )
}

# Duplicated using the "by" argument to avoid copying
getDuplicatedRows_duplicated_by <- function(dt, columnName) {
    return( dt[which( duplicated(dt[,by=columnName]) | duplicated(dt[,by=columnName], fromLast = T)  ),] )
}
```

Then we test that they give the same results

```
results1 <- getDuplicatedRows_Count     (smallDataset, 'id')
results2 <- getDuplicatedRows_duplicated_subset(smallDataset, 'id')
results3 <- getDuplicatedRows_duplicated_by(smallDataset, 'id')

> identical(results1, results2)
[1] TRUE
> identical(results2, results3)
[1] TRUE
```

And the we time the average performance of the 3 solutions:

```
# Small dataset
> system.time( temp <- replicate(n = 100, expr =  getDuplicatedRows_Count            (smallDataset, 'id')) ) / 100
user    system  elapsed 
0.00176 0.00007 0.00186 
> system.time( temp <- replicate(n = 100, expr =  getDuplicatedRows_duplicated_subset(smallDataset, 'id')) ) / 100
user    system  elapsed 
0.00206 0.00005 0.00221 
> system.time( temp <- replicate(n = 100, expr =  getDuplicatedRows_duplicated_by    (smallDataset, 'id')) ) / 100
user    system  elapsed 
0.00141 0.00003 0.00147 

#Large dataset
> system.time( temp <- replicate(n = 100, expr =  getDuplicatedRows_Count            (largeDataset, 'id')) ) / 100
user    system  elapsed 
0.28571 0.01980 0.31022 
> system.time( temp <- replicate(n = 100, expr =  getDuplicatedRows_duplicated_subset(largeDataset, 'id')) ) / 100
user    system  elapsed 
0.24386 0.03596 0.28243 
> system.time( temp <- replicate(n = 100, expr =  getDuplicatedRows_duplicated_by    (largeDataset, 'id')) ) / 100
user    system   elapsed 
0.22080 0.03918  0.26203
```

Which shows that the duplicated() approach scales better, especially if the "by=" option is used.

**UPDATE**: 21 nov 2014. Test of identical output (As suggested by Arun - thanks) identified a problem with me using data.table v 1.9.2 where duplicated's fromLast does not work. I updated to v 1.9.4 and redid the analysis and now the differences is much smaller.

**UPDATE**: 26 nov 2014. Included and tested the "by=" approach to extract column from the data.table (as suggested by Arun so credit goes there). Furthermore the test of runtime was averaged over 100 test to ensure correctness of result.

Comment: Are the answers identical?

Comment: Thanks. `duplicated` for data.tables also has a `by=` argument for specifying column names, instead of having to subset (which copies the data.table).

Comment: Again (what a nice habit) good suggestion Arun - I've updated the answer accordingly, and the by= argument works even better.